# xcode 9 force automatic sign method in exportOptions

Tags: ios, xcode, export, xcode9

I'm using a script to build and archive iOS apps. All was working fine since xcode 9.
Now I receive the following error:

```
  2017-10-20 12:56:12.322 xcodebuild[25449:77625] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fc927c861b0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
      "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"CC.app\" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications and App Groups features.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"CC.app\" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications and App Groups features., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}",
```

I'm using the following exportOptions.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>xxxxxxx</string>
    <key>uploadBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And I DONT WANT specify a provisioning profile, the automatic feature works fine if I archive using xcode, instead of command line.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're missing "provisioningProfiles" option in exportOptions.plist, so instead of using this file, you might try to use a new one, which was created after archiving and exporting IPA manually.

Answer (score 0):

add automatic signingStyle in your exportOptions.plist:

```
<key>signingStyle</key>
<string>automatic</string>
```